# Why was the comment delete button changed from the X icon to the word "Delete"?

Tags: support, comments, design, deleted-comments

**Update:** I found my answer in an answer to another feature request. Basically, this was done for accessibility reasons, as well as to make the style match. I didn't find that post initially because the question there asks about something entirely different; this question helps other users who search for this find that post.

I recently realized I made an incorrect comment, and I proceeded to delete it. However, when I was mousing over the comment to show the button to delete it, I noticed that the button to delete the comment had changed from the gray X symbol to the word "Delete":

> [image: "Delete" shows as a word instead of an icon]

Also, I noticed that the "Edit" button is now capitalized, whereas it used to be lowercase.

Is this an intentional change, or a bug?

Comment: It's intentional: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379654/delete-button-showing-up-as-the-word-delete-rather-than-the-normal-x